# How to go about troubleshoot remote ActiveMQ message broker with low dequeue count

Tags: jmx, activemq

I have a network of brokers configured as such:

- Broker A <=> Broker B
- Broker B <=> Broker C
- Broker A <=> Broker C

I've noticed that in the "Network" tab under "Network Bridges" it lists a table with this information:

- Remote Broker
- Remote Address
- Created By Duplex
- Messages Enqueued

I've noticed that my enqueue counts are significantly higher than my dequeue counts for each network broker. What's the best way to go about identifying the root cause?

One comment to add is, at times there are messages in the DLQ on each broker for messages that were unable to be processed. When a message is tossed in the DLQ of a remote broker, could this explain why the enqueue number grows, but the dequeue number does not?